# How to force NodeJs webapp in docker container to use nginx server_name rather than host:port

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have deployed a Nodejs Express application in a docker container, lets call it **node_container**.
I'm using Nginx server blocks to assign different domain names to each container rather than use the main domain setup to the host's IP. let's call this **maindomain.com**.

without the Nginx virtual host setup, my nodejs application would have been accessed using **maindomain.com:4000** (nodejs listens on 4000). With Nginx reverse proxy, **node_container** is mapped to **nodedomain.com**.

```
maindomain.com:4000 -> nodedomain.com
```

when I visit nodedomain.com I can see my node application.

However, if I click on any link on the app, say a button in my source code with href="/signin",

```
<a href="/signin">...</a>
```

In the deployed web page, it appears as,

```
<a href="http://maindomain.com/signin">...</a>
```

and it goes to **maindomain.com:4000/signin**, not **nodedomain.com/signin**.

Is there a way for me to specify the hostname/domain name that should be the base path for my application so that links in the application will build as

**<custom_hostname>/route**

ex: nodedomain.com/signin ?

TIA!

**EDIT**
I'm on a DigitalOcean droplet with ubuntu. I have several domain names pointed towards My Ubuntu host's IP. One of them is *maindomain.com*.Another is *nodedomain.com*. My node app is listening on port 4000 inside it's container which is mapped to port 4000 of the host. This means it is accessible by *maindomain.com:4000*.

I have a Nginx reverse proxy with server blocks listening on port 80, sending traffic to *maindomain.com* and *nodedomain.com* based on the server_name. the container mapped to maindomain.com, the container with node app and the container with Nginx are on a docker network.

From where does Nodejs pick the host name when it builds the absolute links from relative links? can I specify it to be *nodedomain.com* instead of what is automatically picked, *maindomain.com:4000* ?

Comment: A link like `<a href="/signin">...</a>` will use the host and port of the current page, whatever that happens to be (and this approach is more manageable than hard-coding a domain name and port in your application).  Can you provide a more complete example of your setup?

Comment: I edited the question a little. yes the source code is written as <a href="/signin">...</a>. However, once deployed, the links in the page I visit has a complete url like,  <a href="http://maindomain.com/signin">...</a>.
This seems to me the work of Nodejs. I would like it if there was a say in which domain node would use to prepend. Under the question I will add a small section with the host setup.

Comment: I don't know how it happened. but overnight the problem has solved itself it seems. perhaps docker containers restarted overnight and then the preferred host got picked for some reason? but now the links appear as nodedomain.com/signin

Thanks for the help!